# Как исправить проблему с raid контроллером?

Tags: raid

достался сервер с raid контролером LSI MegaRAID SAS 9240-8i. Собрал на нем 1 рейд, но каждую субботу в 6-00 сервер становится недоступен. Захожу в настройки WebBios и вижу, что рейд в состоянии Check Consistency. Подскажите как можно это исправить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Могу предположить, что каждую субботу в 6-00 сервер грубо перезагружается, и проблема вовсе не в RAID-контроллере.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в настроенном по расписанию MegaRAID consistency check. Отключается командой megacli -AdpCcSched -Dsbl -aALL